# Pointer memory error

Tags: c, embedded, avr

### The problem

I can't get the data from the Flash memory when using the function that return the address of the pattern desired in the Flash (simplified in the example below with only 1 constant : PATTERN_P).

### Some code before explication

The type `patternp` is defined as

```
typedef prog_uchar patternp[NUM_ROWS];
```

The global PATTERN_P variable is an array of type patternp, defined as

```
const patternp PATTERN_P PROGMEM = {
   0b11110000 ,
   0b10010000 ,
   0b10010000 ,
   0b10010000 ,
   0b11110000 ,
   0b10000000 ,
   0b10000000 ,
   0b10000000 
};
```

getpattern():

```
const patternp * getPattern()
{
      //... 
      return &PATTERN_P;
}
```

main():

```
const patternp *bufferPattern = getPattern();

uint8_t rowPatternData[NUMBER_ROW_PER_MATRIX];
const patternp *bufferPattern = getPattern(s[iLetter]);  
for(int iRow = 0; iRow<NUMBER_ROW_PER_MATRIX; iRow++)
{  
    rowPatternData[iRow]=pgm_read_byte( &PATTERN_P[iRow] );   // <--- WORK!
    rowPatternData[iRow]=pgm_read_byte( bufferPattern[iRow] ); // Not Working! 

}
```

### Explications

As you can see, the code get the pattern (in this example, it will return PATTERN_P every time... than I use pgm_read_byte to get the data from the Flash memory. This use the AVR pgmspace (link below). It takes an address and return the data. The code above work when I use the direct access of a template : &PATTERN_P[iRow], but won't work when I use bufferPattern[iRow] or &bufferPattern[iRow]. Any idea?

Reference : pgm_read_byte is defined in [pgmspace](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html)

Comment: What is PATTERN_P? And what is PROGMEM? Please make your codce clearer.

Comment: PATTERN_P is in the code in the question. What do you want more???

Comment: Yes, please post minimal code that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: pgm_read_byte() go read data from the Flash memory. It requires an adress and return data (see the link). The PATTERN_P progmem compile and like say in the question, it does work if in the function OR in the new snipper posted in the question (snippet #2).

Comment: I don't understand what PROGMEM is, can you include its definition. Is it a macro or a compiler extension keyword?

Comment: It's in the question, here is the link again : http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html

Comment: I'm having a really hard time following the question. I tried reformatting your code a bit, but it's not really clear what the question is. What output do you get when it "doesn't work"?
Also, it'd help if you edited the question to *start out* asking the question, and then fill in information to help us answer it. The entire first paragraph makes *no* sense until we've read the entire rest of the question. It doesn't ask a question, and it references code we haven't seen.

Comment: I think your problem is a type conversion that's being made implicitly(without personally hand-working the whole problem).

Comment: I completely reformatted the question, put it more simple I think. Tell me if you need something else.

Comment: Looks a lot better. But I suppose you got it answered already :)

Comment: Thx to all, I might have give too much information from the start and it was my mistake.

Comment: Which C compiler supports the 0b notation for binary numbers?  It certainly isn't in standard C99.

Comment: 0b is usually a prefix for a binary bit pattern.  From the tags, it's probably the AVR compiler.  I've seen it in the Microchip compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bufferPattern is a pointer to an array. When you write bufferPattern[iRow], this does NOT evaluate to a pointer to entry iRow of patternp; the [] operation is acting on the pointer, not the array it points to. What you appear to want to write is &((*bufferPattern)[iRow]).

That will fix the immediate problem. However, the code is  a bit confusing. It may be that your code would be simplified by passing the array directly (C does not pass arrays by value; so it won't copy the array - you don't need to make a pointer to the array to avoid this).

Comment: Excellent information, you got the explication + the solution. And I have learn something! Thanx

Answer (score 1):

this

```
&PATTERN_P[iRow]
```

is

```
&(PATTERN_P[iRow])
```

when your working line gives this:

```
(&PATTERN_P)[iRow]
```